# How to search in binary files

Tags: architecture

I'm working on an application which saves its project files in binary format using [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html). They asked me to come with a design that enables a search mechanism in those project files.

For example, it should be possible to find the projects which contain a specific parameter that is placed deep down in the serialization order.

I'm able to come with 2 unfeasible approaches :

- Deserialize the project file into the corresponding class object and then query the member in question. Repeat this for every project file.

This involves lots of file IO and it would probably be very slow.

- Map the project files into an RDMS as they come and go and query accordingly.

Since the project file is quite complicated, it seems really hard to design the database tables.

What would be your way to go ? I'm open for any kind of method, technology, framework, library...

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that it's a *very* difficult problem to solve. And instead of writing your own potentially buggy and/or crippled implementation, why not use LuceneIndex which already does it all for you?

There are many popular implementations of the library, including in Java, C# and [C++](https://github.com/luceneplusplus/LucenePlusPlus) (which I assume you're interested in).